# Challenge with ASP.NET Web Forms to .NET 8 Razor Pages Migration on Private Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

A old web application needs to be migrated from ASP.NET Web Forms to .NET 8 Razor Pages on a private server. This application can't be access by any public search engine like google.

**Current Setup:**

- Private server name: myServer
- Old web application name: AnnualReport
- Old application uses: ASP.NET Web Forms
- Location: windows > wwwroot$
- Access URL: myServer/AnnualReport/Index.aspx

**Current Situation:**
The application has been successfully migrated to Razor Pages and runs locally through Visual Studion at `https://localhost:7002/`

**Issue:**
I have moved application over to private server But the challenge is: .NET 8 Razor Pages URLs don't use `.cshtml` in the path. My understanding is that by convention, the `Index.cshtml` file in the `Pages` folder acts as the default page for your application. This means you can access it from private server using the following URL: `myServer/AnnualReport/`.

**This URL results in errors:**

- `myServer/AnnualReport/` - Error: 404 - File or directory not found.
- `myServer/AnnualReport/Index` - 'Error: 403 - Forbidden: Access is
  denied.

I haven't encountered a `Startup.cs` file in the project. There's only a `Program.cs` file.

**Is there any configuration needed in the absence of a Startup.cs file (assuming Program.cs handles initialization)?**

**Program.cs File:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```